# Process Builder Attachments

Tags: process-builder

-We use email to case.

-A case is closed if completed
-We have an existing process builder that creates a new case if a customer happens to send another email to the closed case.
- This process builder has a number of actions that update certain fields on this newly created case.

Issue: if the customer sends an attachment in this email to a closed case, the incoming attachment is not related to the new case.

Any suggestions as to how to make sure the incoming attachment is related to the newly created case?

A thought was to scrap the whole create new case process builder, and replace it with an email notification that is sent to the owner of the closed case.  This will prompt them to check in on that case and reopen it manually if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it makes more sense to re-open the case and send an alert for several reasons.

- If the case were considered closed by the person receiving support, that person wouldn't still be sending emails!  (Exception below.)  By re-opening the case, and incrementing a "number_of_times_reopened" number field, you'll be able to report on how many times customer service reps closed cases prematurely.
- If you create a new case instead of re-opening the existing one, how will you ensure that it isn't assigned to a different support agent?  Maybe this isn't a problem, depending on the situation, but it would seem likely.
- ...and, reopening the existing case lets you avoid the orphaned attachment problem.

Of course, you're going to receive the inevitable, "thanks for the help!" emails that always cause trouble when you're doing stuff like this.  You'll want to find a way to filter those out as best you can.  If every "thank you" email created a new case, that would seem to throw off your stats more than it would if it merely reopened a closed case.